# I cant use your captcha to create an account

Tags: discussion, login

I can't use your captcha  to create an account i have tried over 250 times to set up a new account what can I do? I cant see the worlds clearly enough
we have tried to set one up at least 250 tries its unreadable captcha's

please email to me a response at (snip) as to what can I do!

Comment: You appear to have an account (you are limited to one). http://askubuntu.com/users/416678/bill-seward

Comment: Also, this site is indexed and searchable by search engines - don't put your email in public posts because you can get targeted for hacking or spam or other nasty things.